# Show a popup after exporting in Excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel

Hi I've a procedure in my web site for exporting a datatable in xlsx with closedxml library and I want show a popup after finishing export but the popup not showed. Can anyone tell me how to show the popup ? This is my code

```
Protected Sub ExportExcel(dt, strTable)
        Using wb As New XLWorkbook()
            Dim ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "foglio1")
            ws.Columns("I").Style.NumberFormat.Format = "#,##0.00"
            Response.Clear()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & strTable & ".xlsx" )
            try             
                Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                    Response.Flush()
                    Response.Close()
                End Using
            catch
            finally
                Dim scriptString as String = "<script language=JavaScript>"
                scriptString += "alert('Export completed !" & strUser & "!');"
                scriptString += "window.location.href='http://localhost/default.aspx';<"
                scriptString += "/"
                scriptString += "script>"
                If(Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me.GetType(), "clientScript"))
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "clientScript",scriptString)
                end If
            end try
        End Using
```

End Sub

Comment: You mean `MessageBox.Show()`?

Comment: It's a web site